# file reading ,vertex and adjlist

Tags: java

i have to start to create
class file to read a file but i have a problem with delimiter :[,]
class vertex attribut int num;neighbor list
class neighbor attribut int vertexnum;neighbor next;
how can I say that 0 is a vertex and its neighbor vertex is  2 and 9
input file1:
0:[2,9] 1:[8,5,7,2].....
I am beginner, how can I read this file and that 0 is a vertex and its neighbors is 2 and 9, the same for the other vertices

I want to represent the graph with adjacency list 0 have adjancy list 2 and 9..... 
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like (not very robust / resilient and not tested), just to get an idea on how to do it.

I assume that the file is of format

```
0: [2,3,4]
1: [2,4,6]
etc
```

Java code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);

//Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      int vertex = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":")) //get the number before : 
       String neighboorString = (line.substring(line.indexOf("[")+1, line.indexOf("]") //get the string between [ ]
      List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (String neighbor : neighborString.split(",")) { //split the string between , to get the neighbor id
            neighbors.add(Integer.parseInt(neighbor))

       }
       //populate your structure as required)
}
//close the streams/readers
```

Comment: please I want to color this graph with 5 colors for this I ask 2conditions but I do not know how I'm a beginner in java helped me
-if a vertex of graph having 4 neighbor, it can coloer vertex with a color not used by its neighbor
-if a vertex a 5 neighbor is possible to color vertex by colors not used by its neighbors
please how I should do to read the file as I indicate at the top of the page to apply the conditions for coloriers, return the vertex list for each color help me please